# No accede a los archivos de la memoria en Android 10

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Tengo una aplicación para liberar memoria de los dispositivos yendo directamente a carpetas donde se guardan archivos de cache y en especial imágenes o archivos enviados que quedan guardados en el dispositivo.

En las versiones de android inferiores a 10 funciona de maravilla, pero al actualizar mi dispositivo a android 10 noto que lee la memoria pero no lista los archivos, he buscado y no encuentro que se deba solicitar los permisos de forma distinta para la API 29 (Android 10).

Comparto el codigo que utilizo para verificar y solicitar permisos

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

        val PERMISSSION_READ_MEMORY = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val PERMISSION_WRITE_MEMORY = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        if (PERMISSSION_READ_MEMORY == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && PERMISSION_WRITE_MEMORY == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            escaneoMemoriaInteligente().execute()

        } else {

            val dialog = mCreateDialog(this, R.layout.permisos, false)
            dialog.show()

            dialog.bt_entendido_permisos.setOnClickListener {
                dialog.dismiss()
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
            }
        }
    } else escaneoMemoriaInteligente().execute()
```

El `escaneoMemoriaInteligente().execute()` es un Asyntask, aunque esta `deprecated` no creo que sea la razón, ya que sin enviar al AsynTask y listar los archivos con cualquier ruta en otra parte del codigo, tampoco los muestra.

- No me da error en el Log, simplemente no lista los archivos.

Por ejemplo:

```
val list = Utils.memoriaDispositivo.list()
// val list = Utils.memoriaDispositivo.listFiles()
MLog.l("lista de archivos -> $list")
```

Al hacer esto me mostraría por consola la lista de los archivos, pero este es el resultado

[image: Error capture]

Gracias por la colaboración.

*Coloco la etiqueta **java** ya que también manejo ese lenguaje por si la solución la encuentro en el*

Comment: Deberías agregar el código que trata de obtener la lista de archivos.

Comment: @Elenasys jejeje relee la publicación completa, deje un ejemplo de esto que solicitas y los resultados

Answer (score -1):

Primeramente solo es necesario requerir el permiso :

```
  val PERMISSION_WRITE_MEMORY = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

ya que es inherente el permiso `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Ahora con respecto a el problema en el cual no puedes leer el contenido del directorio de almacenamiento externo.

El problema que tienes que **en Android 10, si es que cambiaste el `targetSDK`, ya no se permite de forma predeterminada leer otro directorio, afuera del que se crea para tu aplicación**, de forma predeterminada debes poder leer únicamente en :

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/
```

estos cambios son debidos a seguridad.

Comment: Al solicitar solo el permiso de `PERMISSION_WRITE_MEMORY` no genera el `alertDialog` para que el usuario acepte la lectura de la memoria. Con respecto a que no se puede he visto otras apps que si lo hacen, por eso busco y solicite ayuda en este tema. La app que lo hace (que descargue de Play Store) solicita que el usuario le de acceso a datos de uso **OJO** no es el acceso a los datos(internet) es a los datos de uso. Pero no se como solicitarlo en mi app

Comment: Se que no genera el díalogo lo que comento es que debes tener ese permiso definido de otra forma no puedes leer el directorio. Actualmente con targetSDK 29 no puedes acceder a la ubicación :  /storage/emulated/0 , esto por seguridad